# Find $A_n$ in ﬁnite form

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find $A_n$ in ﬁnite form for

$A_{n+1} - A_n = \frac{1}{n(n+1)}$

Or in other words, in the form such that the number of terms does not grow with n in each of the following cases

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: A couple of "hints".  It matter where you start, e.g. what is $A_1$?  Also we can write $A_n$ as a sum, but the trick to evaluating that sum is recognizing a so-called "telescoping series".  Is it something you studied?

Comment: I tried substituting n by 1,2, and 3 but after I get $A_2-A_1 = 1/2$ , $A_3-A_2=1/6$ and so on I don't understand which step should I take. Am I approaching it the right way?

Comment: @Michelle Why does your question read "in each of the following cases"?  What cases?

Comment: @ErickWong There's 4 types of problems I just can't do this one

Comment: @Michelle I understand that your posting represents a fragment of a larger question.  But the expectation on this site is that each question is self-contained and includes context and evidence that the asker has attempted to solve the problem before seeking help with specific items.  Many users frown upon copy-and-pasted homework questions which represent no effort on the part of the asker, and this gives the same impression of being unwilling to rephrase the question in one's own words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

$$A_{n+1} - A_n = \frac{1}{n(n+1)}=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}$$ makes $$A_{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+1}=A_n+\frac{1}{n}$$ Defining $B_n=A_n+\frac 1n$,  this then leads to  $$B_{n+1}=B_n=c$$ So $$
A_n+\frac{1}{n}=c \implies A_n=c-\frac{1}{n}$$

Comment: You should probably explicitly define $B_n$, no?

Comment: @ErickWong. Done ! Thanks for asking me to precise. Cheers.

Comment: Hi @ClaudeLeibovici thanks for your help but could you explain how did you get $B_{n+1}=B_n$ ? Is it because $B_{n+1}=A_{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+1}$ and you make them equal based on the second equation?

Comment: @Michelle. I defined $B_n$ and if $B_n=B_{n+1}$, I suppose that $B_n$ is a constant. Isn't it correct for you ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici oh I see. Yes thanks!